# Text Scaling on Devices with Different Resolutions

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile, text-size

I am experimenting with text sizes on 2 devices: a Samsung Galaxy Avant and a Samsung Galaxy S6. The specifications for each are found here:

[Samsung Galaxy S6](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s6-6849.php)

[Samsung Galaxy Avant](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_avant-6542.php)

I use the method below to dynamically set the Text Size of a graph axis based on the value in the values > dimens folder for the appropriate screen size:

```
  float axisTextSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.answer_label_text_size), getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    xAxis.setTextSize(axisTextSize);
```

I want both devices to pull the same dimension from the same folder, which they are currently doing. The size is being pulled from the reference in the values > dimens folder, as listed below:

```
<resources>
<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="center_indentation">80dp</dimen>
<dimen name="poll_question_text_size">14sp</dimen>
<dimen name="margin_left">80dp</dimen>
<dimen name="margin_bottom">8dp</dimen>
<dimen name="radio_button_answer_text_size">16sp</dimen>
<dimen name="answer_label_text_size">4sp</dimen>
<dimen name="answer_value_label_text_size">8dp</dimen>
<dimen name="vote_count_label_text_size_lower_right">17sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Right now, I have the size for the answer_label_text_size set at 4sp, yet the sizes are rendering differently on each device. I have increased and decreased the 4sp to see what happens, and it appears that for every increase, the rendering size on the Samsung Galaxy S6 is much greater than on the Avant. In other words, when I increase the text size by 1sp, the result is an increase in 1x on the Avant but an increase in, let's say, 3x on the Galaxy S6. I know the S6 is much higher resolution, but I don't really care about resolution, only the actual, physical size of the device. Why is this happening, and what I am doing wrong?